# Is it worth clearing the map in Anomaly Warzone Earth?

Tags: anomaly-warzone-earth

So far I have been playing AWE by clearing the levels of all towers (I completed only the first few levels though). And although it was not difficult to play that way so far, I wonder if it's actually worth doing since the amount of money gained this way is miserable, levels get quite longer and I think I could have completed all the levels so far without destroying all the towers but by just passing through the "easiest route".

Probably there's an impact on the final score but by "worth doing" I was thinking of something like level/vehicle unlocks. And also if one gains more noticeable amounts of money by destroying stronger turrets later in the game (since in the first few levels destroying all towers meant gaining barely enough gold to buy one more cheapest vehicle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'worth it', but killing all the towers in the level will get you a gold Ruthlessness medal (enough of which gets you a Steam Achievement).

**Edit**: To answer the question of worth: successfully completing a level's objectives (regardless of how efficiently or thoroughly it was done) will unlock the next level and any new vehicles and abilities that may entail. Money is not carried over. The only reason to "fully complete" a level is for the higher score and personal satisfaction.

Comment: I modified my question a bit to make it more clear.